# Compress 5-6 to 5f. in a citation's postnote: \rangelen in \ifnumequal

Tags: biblatex, etoolbox

I am trying to automatically convert page ranges in a postnote given as, e.g., `\textcite[4-5]{Smi83}` to *4f.* iff the range is exactly two pages long. It appears that biblatex' `\rangelen` is made for that, however contrary to the documentation it breaks whenever I try to use it inside etoolbox' `\ifnumequal`:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                \begingroup 
l.36 Test: \ifnumequal{2}{\rangelen{4-5}}
                                        {f.}{something has gone wrong.}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a complete example that shows the error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{%
\ifpages{#1}%
    {\ifnumequal{2}{\rangelen{#1}}%
        {\mkfirstpage{#1}\bibstring{sequens}}%f.
        {\ifnumequal{\rangelen{#1}}{0}% open range
            {\mkfirstpage{#1}\bibstring{sequentes}}%ff.
            {\mkcomprange{#1}}}}% compress closed range
    {#1}}% no range -> just print it

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Smi83,
author = {Smith, S.},
year = {1983},
title = {Sierra},
}
@misc{Jon01,
author = {Jones, J.},
year = {2001},
title = {Juliet},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

% Works:
Rangelen: \rangelen{4-5}

% Breaks:
Test: \ifnumequal{2}{\rangelen{4-5}}{f.}{something has gone wrong.}
%! Missing number, treated as zero.
%<to be read again> 
%                   \begingroup 
%l.36 Test: \ifnumequal{2}{\rangelen{4-5}}
%                                         {f.}{something has gone wrong.}

See e.g. \textcites[4-5]{Smi83}[10-15]{Jon01}. Also see \textcite[42]{Smi83}
and \textcite[90\psqq]{Jon01} as well as \textcite[ although this is only
slightly relevant]{Smi83}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that `\rangelen` is a very poorly written (IMHO) macro that is completely unexpandable, therefore it can't be used in any tests (I lose the point of the macro then if tests aren't the point).

Comment: The `biblatex` manual has an example using `\ifnumcomp`, but I'm not sure it really works.

Comment: It does not,unfortunately. The example uses `\rangelen{\thefield{pages}}`, which (a) uses the field from the bibliography and (b) in my experiments always expands to 1, regardless of the value of `\thefield{pages}`. As soon as I replace `\thefield{pages}` with `#1`, however, it shows the same error as in my original question.

Comment: The issue seems to be dealt with on the `biblatex` side, but has not been resolved with a code commit as of now: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/257.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated `\rangelen` in the development version of biblatex (3.0) on Sourceforge with a re-write by Joseph Wright which addresses this. In addition, there is a new macro `\frangelen` which takes instead a range field (like `pages`) name and returns the range so that you can do:

```
\ifnumequal{2}{\frangelen{pages}}{f.}{something has gone wrong.}
```

This macro requires `biber` as the backend as `biber` calculates this value for all fields of datatype 'range' in the active `biblatex` datamodel and puts the results into the `.bbl`. The benefit of `\frangelen` is that it can deal with many tricky cases:

- Roman numerals (upper and lowercase) in both ASCII and Unicode representations, even special Unicode composed roman numerals.
- Implicit ranges like "22-4" and "132-37"
- Multiple ranges in the same range field like "i-iii, 1-8, 10-20" will result in a length of "21"
- The range separator can be any valid Unicode dash character

You need `biber` 2.0 development version in addition to `biblatex` 3.0

Comment: I can look at doing more 'stuff' at the TeX end in `\rangelen` if required: as much as a technical limitation I'm a bit cautious of the semantics in some of those cases!

Comment: Yes, the semantics are a bit silly in some cases but the ones decomposing unicode roman numerals from Unicode composites are actually very nice and would be horrible to do in TeX without a NFKD library. For example, calculating a range in romans numerals like "U+2165 U+2160 - U+216B" - that's the Unicode precomposed "VI" followed by "I" to make "VII" and the end of the range is the precomposed "XII". The rangelen should be "6". The same as if it was "U+2166 - U+216B" or even ASCII "VII-XII". Hard to do in TeX ...